# Are different colours/frequencies of light travelling along each other or they are superimposed?

Tags: visible-light

When white light is traveling, do its components travel alongside each other without affecting one another?

How is that possible, if they are propagating in same medium at same time at same position, how come they not superimpose and travel as single wave?

(I feel they don't superimpose since prism is able to split them apart)

Comment: They're superimposed. Look up how a prism works.

Comment: You can think of sound ..... 2 or more notes can travel from the piano to your ear ....in the air they are superimposed .... but your ear can pick out the resonant frequencies.

Comment: @ConnorBehan "Prism splits components of different wavelenghts because they travel at different speed in the prism" Now, how is the prism able to tell the different wavelenghts apart if all of them are superimposed, and only a single wave is travelling through it?

Comment: The prism isn't an agent "deciding" how much to slow down each wave. You can think of it as a collection of oscillators being driven by the incoming light as a whole. Superpositions of the driving force still make the oscillator have a well defined response: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/Electromagnetism/node68.html

Answer (score 2):

Photons with any amount of energy/frequencies can all propagate together without affecting one another. Even billions of identical photons, coherently radiating from a common source, propagate as individual photons without affecting each other.

Answer (score 1):

With sound waves, there is a medium. If different frequencies travel together, then they excite the medium together, a superposition is created. However, our senses are able to pick out individual frequencies.

This is different with EM radiation. Photons, regardless of the source, almost never influence each other. They do not need a medium. And they are invariable units from emission to absorption.

The case of superposition, on the other hand, does occur at the receiver. Take two radio waves. When they hit the receiver, both will cause the periodic displacement of electrons on the antenna rod. Depending on the direction in which this occurs, there will be an amplification or a weakening. And ideally, even extinction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you tell me in a nutshell, how the heck are our senses able to pick out individual components of a sound wave? That sounds preposterous. I think of the superimposed wave as the 'new' wave, and the component waves are essentially destroyed(or replaced by new wave). What am I missing?

Comment: So, two(or more) photons can be at the same position at same time and not superimpose. Is this not explainable by considering light as a wave (without concept of photons)?

Comment: Think of the eardrum like a musical drum. Its shape can be a superposition of more basic ones for the same reason that the sound wave hitting it can be a superposition of single notes. This has to do with "linear differential equations" which become quite universal (by Hooke's law) when the amplitudes are small.

Answer (score 1):

Optical instruments like prisms and lenses didn't bring about a crisis in physics the way blackbody radiation or the photoelectric effect did. There were many scientists before the 1900s who understood the dispersion properties of transparent materials very well. When it comes to mathematical concepts like superposition, the physicist should not ask whether it *literally* occurs in nature (the answer to that is always no... every idealized phenomenon has higher order corrections). Instead, she should ask if it's a good model. And superposition for light waves of differing frequency is a good model.

If a device transmits radio waves where the amplitude, frequency or phase is *modulated* (the basis for all wireless communications) then it is true to a high degree of accuracy that it is sending out waves which are superpositions of more basic ones. The statement that it is really sending out photons which create the illusion of superposition seems to be on par with the claim that waves are illusory in water as well. After all, any microscopic description of interacting water molecules has no intrinsic notion of a wave.

Yes, photons improve on these old models in many ways but the linearity of Maxwell's equations is a *consequence* of the fact that photons interact negligibly with each other. Viewing this ability to add two waves as a hypothetical scenario which never needs to be considered in view of photons is a bad idea. It's only possible to talk about photons that come out of a source and go into a detector if they are superpositions of single frequency photons which are necessarily delocalized. Exciting the electromagnetic field with quanta which have no probability of occupying the same position is trying to have our cake and eat it too.

Comment: So the different colours of light travel 'together' without superimposing as photons? And the superposition model of wave cant explain how prism can tell apart different components of white light (if its a single superimposed wave)?